# Not claims comes from cookie in ASP.NET CORE AUTHENTICATION

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api

i'm making a test with authentication services in a ASP.NET 6 api.
With Login endpoint, i created a user whith a claim, but in the "username" endpoint, when i try to get claims,  seem like not claims has stored in the cookie.

Fullcode:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie")
    .AddCookie("cookie");

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/username", (HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    // HERE => allClaims is empty! Why?
    var allClaims = ctx.User.Claims.ToList();
    
    var userName = ctx.User.FindFirst("usr");
    return ctx.User.FindFirst("usr")?.Value??"usr not found in claims";
});

app.MapGet("/login", async (HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("usr", "mariano") };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookie");
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
        IsPersistent = true
    };

    await ctx.SignInAsync("cookie", user, authProperties);
    return "ok";
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authentication-concepts) is handled by the authentication service, IAuthenticationService, which is used by authentication middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but you simply need to enable authentication. The mechanism that makes your code work is not in action.

```
// Add the authentication middleware that will do the magic with cookies
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Run();
```

---

Note: instead of `"cookie"` I'd suggest to use the constant `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` which has a value `"Cookies"`.

---

At the same time, it looks like you are potentially trying to reinvent a wheel.

Fully-custom implementation of authentication/authorization is highly discouraged.

I'd suggest using existing solutions for this.

You can consider IAM solutions:

- [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) (free tier)
- [Auth0](https://auth0.com/pricing) (free plan)

Or just configure an OpenID app with Identity Providers like:

- Google,
- Facebook,
- etc.

Comment: Indeed, the app.UseAuthentication() was missing. And so it is, it's just an exercise to understand how authentication works. This is just learning code and not production code. Thanks for your answer.